# Click search input when the webview is opened automatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, webview

I have a webview application with fragment. In this application, I redirect to different pages. These pages have a search box in the header section. Clicking this search box input automatically enlarges and covers the entire page. To make it more usefull with my mobile app, I want it to automatically click on this box when fragment opens

I also have jsoup in my project I use this library to try hide some objects in webview but I still haven't found how to use it. I've been searching for 3 days, but still haven't found it. Can you offer me a source on this subject too

[app appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20yH8.jpg)

here my codes

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
        WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webViewsearch);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        return view;
    }

} ``
```